# how to track android branch using git

Tags: android, git

all

I have downloaded source code from google android website following google's guide. My purpose is to create a local branch to track remote branch

take framework/media for example, you can see .git under this directory, but when you run

`git branch`

the output is

`*no branch`

I crate my local branch using

`git checkout -b local`

then I have the problem, how can I switch back to track remote branch, I cannot pull updated source code from google for this .git again. There is only one local branch.

I also tried

`git remote`

and get

`aosp    https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base (fetch)`

aosp    https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base (push)

`git branch --track local aosp`

but I get the error

`fatal: Not a valid object name: aosp`

Anybody can give me some advice and guide? thanks very much.

Comment: Clone remote branch first, then create a new local branch you can modify in.

Comment: If one of the answers presented below worked for your question, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the green outline of a checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use...

```
git branch --track local aosp/master
```

(The reason you're getting an error is because `aosp` is a remote, not a specific thing on that remote. `aosp/master` refers to the `master` branch on that remote, and thus can be tracked.)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[How do you make an existing git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)"

> As of Git 1.7.0:

```
 git branch --set-upstream local aosp/local
```

will work too.
Note that for git 1.8+, [discussions are in progress](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/1-8-0-Change-branch-set-uptream-to-take-an-argument-td5979988.html) in order to make `aosp/local` an *argument* of `--set-upstream` (instead of a separate parameter).

> In order to make its usage unambiguous, and to allow it to be used w/o specifying the current branch, require it to take an argument like so:

```
(master)$ git branch --set-upstream=origin/master
```